# Initial state in Sysml Activity diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, sysml

I have a question for Initial state for Activity diagram.

> I have 3 Swimlanes in my sub-Activity diagram. The initial state in the sub-activity diagram depends on triggered events in which Swimlanes it shall start. 
>   Is it possible to place the decision block in center of the swimlane ??. as shown in the below diagram.[image]

Comment: In the activity diagrams I have seen the swimlanes represented some clear "actor" with clear responsibility. What are the real (expanded) names of the swimlanes? What do they represent? What's the real name of the DecisichNode1? Who (which actor, may be some not shown) will be responsible for evaluating the conditions and moving the token to the next activity?

Comment: @xmojmr Probably some consultancy is needed over there ;-)

Comment: Here the Swimlanes are represents  Components. AND the DecisionNode1 is generalized  decision if the Task1 shall be be triggerred in FUSI_Functionality OR Task2 shall be shall triggered.                                        My Question is it possible to have the decisionnode on the boundary line of the Swimlanes.  (and its a SysML activity diagram)

Comment: @xmojmr meant the lanes. Yours are not classified - the colon in front is missing.

Comment: What does the drawing **mean**, what do the abstract terms stand for?  From the drawing perspective you can place the decision diamond anywhere, even where it is not visible and it's use is unclear. For better help we will need some less general and more concrete description of your diagram. Not "_a car_" by "_my blue Honda Civic EX-L Coupe_". See page #42 in [SysML vs. UML 2: A Detailed Comparison](http://ecs.victoria.ac.nz/foswiki/pub/Events/MODELS2011/Material/MODELS_2011_T2-Roques-SysML_UML2.pdf) for example of what @thomas-kilian meant

Answer (score 3):

It's possible but it's not readable. The incoming arrow is hidden by the lane drawing. Place the diamond above the lanes.